# c# - How to close the main form without letting the application close?

Tags: c#, winforms

What i want to do:
->Open a MDI form
->Close the projects main form
->Without closing the application

What i have done:

```
frmMain fm = new frmMain();
fm.Show();
this.Close()
```

**Any help would be appreciated! :)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you actually wish to close the main form, but leave the application running, you can make your default class launch the application context:

```
using(MyContext myContext = new MyContext())
{
    Applicaton.Run(myContext);
}
```

where `MyContext` inherits from `ApplicatonContext`.

Your application context can then load and close forms as needed. I do this with one project where I have the context launch a login form. Only after it is completed successfully does the main form get loaded. I also allow the "logging out" from the program to be handled by terminating the main form and reloading the login form.

EDIT: From the comments, it may be that all you are looking for is .Hide(). This doesn't cause your form to unload and a call to .Show() will restore it (for example, you can use a timer or another form holding a reference to your main form to make the call). I prefer to use an ApplicationContext because it takes the responsibility for keeping your program in memory away from a UI element which the user may attempt to close.

Comment: i didnt understand! i dont know about contexts in c#! please can you give another way?

Comment: Doesn't this over complicate things? In the log-in window example, you could just open-dialog it from the main window's ctor, even before initializing components, etc. I really think that all he's looking for is `Hide()`, but I would love to hear why that won't suffice.

Comment: A context is just a wrapper to manage the forms for your project. If your default class for the project calls it as noted, you can then launch any forms or run any background processes from there. See: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/johnconwell/ApplicationContexttoEncapsulateSplashScreenFunctionality11232005041406AM/ApplicationContexttoEncapsulateSplashScreenFunctionality.aspx for an example of it in use.

Comment: @YoryeNathan, from his response, it probably does over complicate things, but I made the wrong assumption he knew about .Hide() and was looking for a code container.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Hide method.

Try doing this:

```
frmMain fm = new frmMain();
this.Hide();
fm.Show();
```

Or:

```
frmMain fm = new frmMain();
this.Hide();
fm.ShowDialog();
this.Show();
```

The latter will open the window, and once it is closed, the previous window will reappear.

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly and is just as simple as the other answers. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

What I did to get around this is:

```cs
this.Hide()
```

Probably not the best way to do this, but still.

You could even get it back by calling

```
this.Show()
```