# both forms close unexpectedly when second form appears

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

I want to close first form when second is show. But all forms closes **unexpectedly!** I couldn't understand why. Please, explain me *it's cause*  and help me to do this correctly.

My codes:

```
private void b_digerForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
    F_Diger digerForm = new F_Diger();
    digerForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

P.S: I'm new to C#. I searched out about this problem, but couldn't find any helpful post.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You opened the form with ShowDialog. That means that when the main form closes all dialog windows will also close. You could use digerForm.Show(); to keep that second form open.

Comment: thanks for quick response! I also tried it, but result is the same.

Comment: Is digerForm launched from program.cs Application.Run(new digerForm()); ?

Comment: nope. I didn't add any new line to `program.cs` file. I just try it.

Comment: If you open program.cs there should be a line that says something similar to Application.Run(...); If your digerForm is your main form then what is likely happening is when you close digerForm your program is exiting this would also cause all form associated with it to close.

Comment: The fact that they all close has nothing to do with using `ShowDialog` it is about what form owns which other forms

Comment: Ah @Sayse you appear to be correct. I had never actually looked. I incorrectly assumed that showdialog without parameters defaulted the windows parent to be the currently active window which in most cases would have been the form that the dialog was launched from. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since the this is the main form, you have to hide it, instead of closing it, or else run your application in a different context.

```
private void b_digerForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    this.Hide();
    F_Diger digerForm = new F_Diger();
    digerForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: With `Hide()` method **only the program GUI** disappears. It works in background. But I **must** close it when second form opens.

Comment: May be you should take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11004247/823369

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are trying to close the main form, and by doing so you are closing any forms that are a child of that form (form2). Your best option would be to hide the form1 whilst you are viewing the second, with `this.Hide()`.

Just remember to close it *after* you are done with form2

Comment: Thanks. I understand what's the problem.

Comment: With `Hide()` method only the program GUI disappears. But it works in background. So, I must close it when second form opens.

Comment: @MirjalalTalishinski - I think what you may have misunderstood is that a (winforms) application runs by having one main window that then can open sub dialogs (child dialogs).. You can open another application from the `program.cs` file but it may help if you explained what the forms do

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
private void b_digerForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

{

```
F_Diger digerForm = new F_Diger();
digerForm.ShowDialog(this);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Change the Program.cs file so that no main form is defined for the application.

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        Form FormLogin = new FrmLogin();
        FormLogin.Show();

        Application.Run();
    }
}
```